# How can I get android notification badges/application icon badges to work on an Android Studio Emulator? (React Native Application)

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, react-native

how can I configure application icon badges to work within the context of a react native application, and to work with some kind of android emulator (I know this only works with certain devices).

Example, where gmail is showing 62 new emails in their application icon badges: 
https://static1.squarespace.com/static/559ca9fce4b0015f541296e6/t/597ae902197aeafed282e5b7/1501227280088/action_launcher_unread_badges_with_notification_preview.png?format=1500w

I believe I have the code correct, but it is just not working with the emulators I have used. Here is my code that I'm using:

BadgesModule.java:

````
```

package com.myapp.badges;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

import me.leolin.shortcutbadger.ShortcutBadger;


public class BadgesModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;


 /* constructor */
  public BadgesModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "BadgesModule";
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void applyCount(){
      ShortcutBadger.applyCount(reactContext, 3);
      }
}
```
````

BadgesPackage.java:
    ```

````
package com.myapp.badges;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class BadgesPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
      List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
      modules.add(new BadgesModule(reactContext));
      return modules;
    }

    // Deprecated from RN 0.47
    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```
````

MainApplication.java:

````
```
package com.myapp;

import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.myapp.badges.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {

    @Override
    protected String getJSBundleFile() {
      return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new RNHockeyAppPackage(MainApplication.this),
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new MapsPackage(),
            new RNI18nPackage(),
            new LocationPackage(),
            new BadgesPackage(),
            new RNFusedLocationPackage(),
          new CodePush(null, getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.DEBUG)
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```
````

App.js:

````
```
...
import { NativeModules, } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component{
...
componentDidMount(){
    NativeModules.BadgesModule.applyCount()
}
...
render(){...}
}
```
````

The emulators I've used are: 
Galaxy Nexus API 27
Nexus 5X API 28
Nexus 6 API 27
Pixel 2 XL API 26